# How in PHP to take two unix time stamps and display a date range across months where the 2nd date is simplified

Tags: php, date

Using PHP I'd like to take two unix time stamps and display the date as such if they span different months:

December 6th 2013 - January 8th, 2014

but to show date ranges like this:

December 6th - 8th, 2013

when they don't span across a month or year.

My current code is below (obviously this doesn't do what I'm looking for).  Hoping someone else has worked this out or it's hidden somewhere in date() and I just don't know about it.

```
<?php
// Date
$startDate = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'wvc_session_start_timestamp', true );
$startDatePretty = date( 'F jS Y', $startDate);
$endDate = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'wvc_session_end_timestamp', true );
$endDatePretty = date( 'F jS Y', $endDate);

$html .= '<div class="event-date">';
    // check if the custom field has a value

if( ! empty( $startDate ) ) {
    $html .= $startDatePretty;
} 

// check if the custom field has a value
if( ! empty( $endDate ) ) {
    if( $endDatePretty != $startDatePretty ) {
        $html .= ' - ' . $endDatePretty;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Think I've got the logic worked out myself. Might be a cleaner/simpler way, but this gets me what I want for now until I optimize it.

```
// Date
$startDate = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'wvc_session_start_timestamp', true );
$endDate = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'wvc_session_end_timestamp', true );

if (empty($startDate) || empty($startDate)) {
    $startDatePretty = date( 'F jS, Y', $startDate);
    $endDatePretty = date( 'F jS, Y', $endDate);
} else {
    $startDatePretty = date( 'F jS', $startDate);
    $endDatePretty = date( 'jS, Y', $endDate);
    // Different year
    if (date('Y',$startDate) != date('Y',$endDate)) 
        $startDatePretty .= date( ', Y', $startDate );

    // Different month
    if (date('F',$startDate) != date('F',$endDate))
        $endDatePretty = date( 'F', $endDate) . $endDatePretty;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check if dates are in the same month or not:

```php
if (date('Ym', $startDate) == date('Ym', $endDate)) {
    echo date('F jS - ', $startDate), date('jS, Y', $endDate), "\n";
} else if (date('Y', $startDate) == date('Y', $endDate)) {
    echo date('F jS - ', $startDate), date('F jS, Y', $endDate), "\n";
} else {
    echo date('F jS Y - ', $startDate), date('F jS Y', $endDate), "\n";
}
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/85388)</kbd>

Comment: Simpler, but if the months are different and the year the same I only want the first date output to show the month.  ie. Jan 1st - Feb 1st 2014, not Jan 1st 2014 - Feb 1st 2014.

Comment: @jb510: just add another `if statement`, see **demo** in updated answer.